# How to properly append JWT token in request header in Angular 7 + Laravel 5.7

Tags: angular, laravel, rest, http-headers, jwt

I have this in my `UsersService` in my Angular 7 app.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { ApiService } from '../../services/api.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsersService {

  public headers: Headers;
  public options: RequestOptions;

  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    public api: ApiService
  ) {

    this.headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'X-Token': localStorage.getItem('token')
    });
    this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });

  }

  getAll(){

    return this.http.get(`${this.api.url}/api/users`, this.options);

  }

}
```

This service will send `HTTP` request to my Laravel 5.7 app with endpoint `/users`

Laravel Routes `api.php`:

```
<?php

Route::group([

    'middleware' => 'api'
    // 'prefix' => 'auth'

], function ($router) {

    /**
     * Authentication API
     */
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('signup', 'AuthController@signup');
    Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
    Route::post('me', 'AuthController@me');

    /**
     * Users API
     */
    Route::get('users', 'UsersController@index');

});
```

Laravel `UsersController`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;

class UsersController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api');
    }

    /**
     * Get all Users
     * 
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $user = User::all();

        return response()->json($user);

    }
}
```

When trying call the said endpoint it returns an error:

```
message:"Unauthenticated."
```

How to properly append the JWT Token to send in the endpoint?

Comment: Need to pass `'Authorization': 'Bearer ${token}'` as a header, also

Answer (score 0):

First import **HttpHeaders** from

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders,HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

private token=localStorage.getItem('token');
```

Now create http headeer in the following way

```
private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +this.token ,'Content-Type':'application/json', 'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'})
  };
```